# Allocating contiguous array of non-default constructed templated structs

Tags: c++, memory, struct, allocation

I'm writing a C++ library in a multi-threaded application where performance is important, and am not sure of the best way to achieve my goal of allocating a fixed-size array of templated structs. I'd like a single contiguous block of memory for cache locality, and pad the cache lines to avoid false sharing.

Here's the struct definition:

```
template<size_t buf_bytes, size_t cache_pad_bytes>
struct PaddedBuffer {
    char buf[buf_bytes];
    char cache_line_padding[cache_pad_bytes];
}
```

Ideally the contiguous block of memory would look something like this, and be accessible as an array:

```
[ {buf, pad}, {buf, pad}, ..., {buf, pad} ]
```

where [ ] indicates the array, and { } indicates a struct. The fundamental challenge is that the size of buf is not known until runtime.

This is what I really want to be able to do, but given that buf_bytes is not a constant expression, the C++ standard doesn't allow this with a templated function (of course).

```
PaddedBuffer<buf_bytes, cache_pad_bytes> buffers[num_buffered_entries];
```

I can think of a couple options, but don't really like any of them. Is there a better way?

**Option 1: Dynamically allocate everything**
Change the PaddedBuffer definition to make the buffer a pointer (char* buf). Then, dynamically allocate an array of PaddedBuffer*, and then dynamically allocate as `num_buffered_entries` of them. This isn't ideal because the buffers aren't going to [necessarily] be adjacent.

**Option 2: Dynamically allocate one large buffer**
I can essentially allocate a big chunk of memory of size `(num_buffered_entries * (buf_bytes + cache_pad_bytes)`, then define my own operator[] function, and just use it pretty much as normal after that. I think this works, but feels a bit hacky. Also, I loose the named struct accessor ability, so I can't add a field `foo` to the struct and just write `object.foo`. I'd have to manage that myself. In this case, I only need the buffer (not the cache line padding) so it doesn't really matter, but it does feel a bit like I'm reinventing the wheel.

(Note: I realize I can use a `std::vector` and initialize it with a copy constructor, but I don't want a std::vector for a variety of reasons.)

A bit more background on the problem I'm solving: This data structure is essentially used for a lock-free single-producer producer-consumer queue, where the buffers are reused thousands or millions of times throughout the course of the application. I'd like to be able to allocate the memory once at the beginning of the program and then access the memory efficiently (and without false sharing). I'm assuming I can achieve good higher level cache locality by allocating this as a contiguous chunk; I'm assuming I can obviate false sharing with the cache line padding. (I did investigate using related libraries (TBB, Boost, TBB) and they were close but didn't quite map to my problem given.) This is in the inner loop of a large library, and therefore want it to be reasonably fast. I can just go with one of these options (Option 1 would be the most straightforward) if there isn't a clean solution, but if there is a clean solution, I'd like to use it. Note that the queue is intended to be of a fixed size, and therefore is implemented as a circular buffer with bounds appropriate checking.

Is there a cleaner and recommended approach?

Comment: I think you might be approaching the problem in the wrong way.  Can you detail out what you are trying to accomplish and we can help you come up with a cache friendly, non-false sharing solution?

Comment: Before you go into micro-managing things like this, have you *measure* that it is a bottleneck in your program? Any optimization you do in the source *will* add a degree of unmaintainability, especially if you do it before you even *know* there is a problem. Remember that the compiler is usually very good when it comes to optimizations, including adding good padding to structures.

Comment: It seems to me that there are two conflicting informations: If you know at compile time what struct you are going to save in there, then you have constant buf_bytes: sizeof(Struct). If you don't know at compile time, then the "named struct accessor" is impossible anyway and the Option 2 seems ideal. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Why not just `alignas` from `c++11`?

Comment: I think you need to look at the allocator concept, this kind of work (alignment, blocking and padding) sounds like work for an allocator.

Comment: @NathanOliver sure I've added more details to the post

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I certainly appreciate your sentiment. This is in the inner loop and and a hot spot as determined by perf_events, but it's not so hot that I need to write incredibly complicated code. I'm hoping I can just learn about some aspect of C++ or best practice that will be both efficient and reasonably well written/maintainable.

Comment: @michalsrb buf_bytes and cache_pad_bytes are not constant expressions and therefore the size of the struct is not known at compile time.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your requirements exactly, by why not simplify things taking a different approach? As long as the buffer entries are not interrelated, and you don't really need say, read or write 2 or more of them at once, they can be all dynamically allocated (during initialization), and there is not really any performance benefit from having them allocated as a single block. You don't really have any way to control caching, and having them is a contiguous block doesn't guarantee anything, esp if the buffer is large.(cont)

Comment: I would consider a different implementation, which is employ a "pool" kind of structure - implement it the way you like, only req is atomic access. Producer threads would get an available entry from the pool, store their output there and send it to the consumer queue. Producers should put the entry back into the pool, after they are done. And this IS efficient, as the entries aren't really allocated/freed all the time. Access to the pool data structure should be serialized, but this is no problem as you only keep it locked very briefly, just to get or store a buffer entry (pointer) there.

Comment: To clarify things, could you add to the question what would be the ideal outside interface of the array/container?